# Recargar una página con Window jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy realizando una función , lo cual con un botón abre un vista, pero quiero ahora en vez de abrir la página, haga un refresh, este es mi código

```
    $("#button").click(function () {
    Array = [];
 //code 
    if (Array.length > 1) {
        Array = [];
        swal({
            title: l.message,
            text: "",
            imageUrl: "/assets/img/icon-info.jpg"
        });
    }
    else if (Array.length > 0) {

               window.open("http://" + window.location.host + "/Google/Api?Number=" + yourArray);
    }
    else {

        window.open("http://" + window.location.host + "/Google/Api");
    }
});
```

Lo he intentado de esta manera pero no me funciona

```
 window.location.reload("http://" + window.location.host + "/google/api");
```

Comment: Porque agregas el mismo array dos veces?

Comment: @Mario Guiber que tiene que ver el Array con hacer un refresh, un window.reload, no afecta el Array, el primer Array se declara como global, estoy usando Ajax para la solicitud de informacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
        $("#button").click(function () {
        Array = [];
    //code 
        if (Array.length > 1) {
            Array = [];
            swal({
                title: l.message,
                text: "",
                imageUrl: "/assets/img/icon-info.jpg"
            });
        }
        else if (Array.length > 0) {
            window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Google/Api?Number=" + yourArray;
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Google/Api";
        }
    });
```

Comment: gracias me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que estas queriendo hacer es algo así, en un botón refresca la pagina sobre la cual estas parado, y la otra abre sobre la misma ventana una nueva url.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
    window.location.reload();
  });
  $("#myButton1").click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myButton">Refrescar esta misma pagina</button>
<button id="myButton1">Cargar en esta ventana una nueva url</button>
```